# How do I run two separate threads printing numbers (or words) in ascending and descending order?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I need to write a program for my online class. Here is the prompt:

> Write a program to run two separate threads printing numbers (or words) in ascending and descending orders. The numbers (or words) should be given by the user.

I think I have the threads down, but I'm confused on how I would have the code take the user input and then print it in either ascending/descending order. So basically I'm confused on the syntax/methods that would need to be used.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim A As System.Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ThreadA)
        Dim B As System.Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ThreadB)
        A.Start()
    End Sub

    Sub ThreadA()
        Dim nl As String = Environment.NewLine
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a word:")
        Dim x = Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub ThreadB()
        Dim nl As String = Environment.NewLine
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a word:")
        Dim x = Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: It doesn't say the number should be given inside each threads, just that the displaying of information should be in a thread. I think it doesn't make sense since displaying two things at the same time will create a mess. Unless both thread don't need to run at the same time.

Comment: @the_lotus Each thread could use a different identifier when it prints, but yeah it will be confusing

Comment: From what I understand, you should first get a list of inputs from the user (a loop with Console.ReadLine), then print that loop using two different threads, each of them iterating the list of inputs in opposite directions.

Comment: Is it a requirement to do it in the console?  Because two threads printing stuff to the same console is going to be confusing.  I would do it in a simple gui with two text boxes for output.

Comment: Either way, the assignment is pointless bordering on the edge of perverse. Console I/O is fully thread-safe (locks are used under the hood), so it works when you do it, but it's pointless because you aren't gaining any speed or other improvement by doing it on multiple threads. It just makes the code more complicated and introduces the possibility for more errors. If you do it in a GUI, then it *isn't* thread-safe, and you have to specifically make it that way using something like `Invoke`, since all UI happens on a single thread by design. So it's harder and *still* pointless. @Velocibadgery

Comment: @CodyGray most homework assignments are pointless. I think it's designed to teach about how threads are working "simultaneously".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you've misunderstood the question slightly. The program below takes input for 5 numbers each for two word lists, sorts each wordlist and then starts 2 threads to write each word to the console. The multi-threading is demonstrated by the way the lines from each wordlist are output to the console.

Each list is in fact in alphabetical order but multi-threading means that as both of the pieces of code run "at the same time", they don't run at **exactly** the same time, so the output statements don't get printed in exact alternate order. You might get a few of one word list clumped together because of the way multi-threading happens. I've added a line to sleep each thread for different amounts of time to highlight the threads running independant of each other.

```
Module Module1
    Dim wordlist1 As New List(Of String)
    Dim wordlist2 As New List(Of String)

    Sub Main()
        Dim A As System.Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ThreadA)
        Dim B As System.Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ThreadB)
        Dim word As String
        For i As Integer = 1 To 5
            Console.WriteLine("Enter List 1 word " & i.ToString & ":")
            word = Console.ReadLine()
            wordlist1.Add(word)
        Next

        For i As Integer = 1 To 5
            Console.WriteLine("Enter List 2 word " & i.ToString & ":")
            word = Console.ReadLine()
            wordlist2.Add(word)
        Next

        Dim sortOrder As String = ""
        Do
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to sort in ascending order or descending. Enter 'a' or 'd'")
            sortOrder = Console.ReadLine().ToLower
        Loop Until sortOrder = "a" Or sortOrder = "d"

        wordlist1.Sort()
        wordlist2.Sort()

        If sortOrder = "d" Then
            wordlist1.Reverse()
            wordlist2.Reverse()
        End If

        A.Start()
        B.Start()
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

    Sub ThreadA()
        For Each word As String In wordlist1
            Console.WriteLine("List 1 :" & word)
            Thread.Sleep(40)
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub ThreadB()
        For Each word As String In wordlist2
            Console.WriteLine("List 2 :" & word)
            Thread.Sleep(80)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```